# Texmaker: command not found on MacOS El Capitan

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I recently upgraded my Mac to El Capitan. After installing the new Version of MacTex, I changed all appearances of `/usr/texbin` in the texmaker settings to `/Library/TeX/texbin/`. Normal tex seems to work just fine, but tikzpictures with tikzexternal don't.

I added `-shell-escape` to the pdflatex command which worked fine before the upgrade to El Capitan. Now I get an error saying "sh: pdflatex: command not found" on the tikzpicture.

When I copy & paste the command from texmaker to the console (and insert the filename) it compiles without any problems.

After doing that, texmaker works fine until I change the tikzpicture (which should be because it doesn't try to recompile it when there are no changes made to it)

This is the error I get in texmaker:

```
 Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/weak-scaling" "\def\tikzexternalreal
job{journal}\input{journal}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/weak
-scaling' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have
enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes
it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simpl
y failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/weak-scaling.log'. If you contin
ue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

The error message says there would be more information in `weak-scaling.log` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. El captain update causes lot of problems due to PATH use modification. Perhaps other post since two days on the subject may help you `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with texmaker on El Capitan yesterday which gave me a `sh: repstopdf: command not found` whenever I was trying to use a new `eps` graphic in my document. Apparently changing the specific paths to `pdflatex` etc. is not enough and it might still try looking for some binaries (when needed e.g. for converting images) in `/usr/texbin`.

I found a solution [here](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-August/037286.html) which suggests using the input field at the bottom of the command settings tab to add `/Library/TeX/texbin/` to the PATH variable. After that everything worked fine for me. I'm a bit surprised that it doesn't find pdflatex in your case though because you have probably specifically set its path to `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`, but I hope that this still solves your problem.

So my settings now look like this:

Note the active input box at the bottom which sets the PATH for the other binaries.

[image]

Comment: I really thought I already tried that. But apparently something was different when I last tried it. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear both. Can you show us, how your lines looks like under "Preferences" and "Command build"?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my Command settings. I hope that helps.

Comment: In my case, I had to set the path to '/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/'

Comment: $ ls /usr/texbin
ls: /usr/texbin: No such file or directory

Comment: -bash: /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Please read the information about MacTeX and El Capitan at http://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html and, especially, the `Updating For El Capitan' document linked there. While MacTeX-2015 installs the necessary link it is possible to create that link if you read Section 8 of that document.

The most recent versions of the GUI applications supplied by MacTeX will (almost) auto-config to the change in link. I suspect many other apps (e.g., TeXmaker) have supplied updates that do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the directories, and it did not work. However, I delete Tex and Texmaker from the applications folder and download the most recent mactex (May 2015) and texmaker (Oct 2015) and install both again and now is working,