# Problem when compiling, file not found, after update to El Captain

Tags: texmaker, paths

I already see all the questions related to the change of directory path everywhere in the `texmaker` settings. I follow those steps and I change all the paths with the: `/Library/TeX/texbin`but I still have problem when compiling. The error is the following: `log file not found` if the file is new. Otherwise there is no errors but the Pdf view doesn't appear and the compilation isn't done.

Any idea? What I'm missing?

Comment: Can you compile the document from a terminal, using either `pdflatex` or `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` (or another engine like `xelatex` if that's what you're using)? Are there any files in `/Library/TeX` at all?

Comment: @MikeRenfro inside `/Library/TeX` I have only Documentation, Distribution, Local and Root. From the terminal I don't have any command called `pdflatex`.

Comment: I don't have El Capitan to confirm with, but my guess is that either `pdflatex` isn't in the texbin directory, or isn't present at all. You can confirm that with something like `find /Library/TeX -name pdflatex` and see if it returns a path at all. If not, I'd consider reinstalling MacTeX.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Ok, thanks for your suggestion. I can't find any path for the pdflatex so I'll try to reinstall MAcTex. Thanks again.

Comment: many questions on el capitan!  is this helpful?  [Texmaker: command not found on MacOS El Capitan](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271221/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I already try all these solutions. But the problem still present. Now I'm trying to reinstall MacTeX

Comment: @MikeRenfro I tried to reinstall MacTeX now I have the files inside Library/Tex but a problem is still present. The pdf document now is created but the viewer doesn't show it. Moreover, every time I open again TexMaker the path must be re-set. How I can save in a permanent way the right path? Thanks for your support.

Comment: I don't use TeXmaker in OS X, only TeXshop. But can you compile from a terminal now? If not, no editors' build buttons will likely work.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I checked, now the compilation works properly.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I still have the problem to re-set the path each time I open TexMaker. Do you know how to deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by changing the path and save it under administration permission.