# Latexmk Command not found after MacOS El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: latexmk, mac

I recently upgraded to El Capitan on my mac, and as a result, terminal no longer recognizes the command "latexmk". For example, I get the following from terminal:

```
Tylers-MacBook-Pro:Dropbox SaiyanSparta$ latexmk -pvc -pdf cat.tex
-bash: latexmk: command not found
```

I use vim for my text editor and obviously compile with latexmk in the terminal. Prior to my upgrade, "latexmk" worked perfectly fine, but now it does not work ata ll. Does anyone know of any potential fix for this? I checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271221/texmaker-command-not-found-on-macos-el-capitan?lq=1/%22this%22) article but I didn't really understand what it meant. Can anyone help me out, preferably in layman terms? Thanks!

Comment: Apple made some configuration changes in El Capitan that changed the location of the latexmk command file. These are detailed in the installation notes for the LaTeX editor TexStudio. I'm not in reach of my MacBook right now so I ant give you the exact details but the above might give you the clues you need to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense since none of my latex compilers are compiling. I'll try to study the above more then.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a look at tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf

Comment: Turns out all I needed to do was download Fix_Tex from http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/  after reading the above. Thank you very much for the help again! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgraded from a comment since it seems to have solved the problem: Apple made some configuration changes in El Capitan that changed the location of the latexmk command file. These are detailed in the installation notes for the LaTeX editor TexStudio. I'm not in reach of my MacBook right now so I can't give you the exact details but the above might give you the clues you need to fix this problem. Also, have a look at tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf