# Using \tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, tikz-external, standalone

I want to use `tikzexternalize` in my document, because the amount of tikz pictures is quite large. In general my tikz pictures are generated using `matlab2tikz` providing every tikz picture as a `standalone`. For the example the main document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includestandalone[width=0.8\linewidth]{./fig_01}
\caption{mycaption}
\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

Within the file `fig_01` the following simplified code was generated using `matlab2tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

While excluding lines 7 and 8 from the main the compilation works fine - not so with the externalization activated.

My compilation command for `pdflatex` within TexStudio is:

```
"/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Comment: You need to ass `--shell-escape` for externalisation to work.

Comment: I just found the answer to my question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271221/texmaker-command-not-found-on-macos-el-capitan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question using this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271221/texmaker-command-not-found-on-macos-el-capitan). While `pdflatex` including the option `-shell-escape` couldn't be found during former compilations, everything works fine now. Changing the folder for the commands to **/Library/TeX/texbin/...** and adding the same into the **Build->Commands ($PATH)** in the settings did what i was looking for.

Comment: They should be found without this is `PATH` is correctly configured. At least, that's the theory. (Unless Apple have decided to disable this or something.)

Comment: Oh, you're using a system updated from the previous OS to El Captain? That's a box of Apple-specific darkness ;).

Answer (score 6):

Externalisation relies on 'shell escape'. When this is restricted or disabled, externalisation can't work because it requires the compiler to spawn additional compilation commands in order to create each picture separately.

By default, this feature is disabled for security reasons. A restricted set of commands may be spawned, but this set is not sufficient for the compilation of the pictures.

Hence, you need to override the default setting by explicitly allowing unrestricted shell escape for the compilation:

```
"/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape
```

Comment: This must be a duplicate, though.

Comment: Adding `--shell-escape` respectively `-shell-escape` to the compilation command leads to the following error:

sh: pdflatex: command not found

and furthermore:

Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
No file document.aux.
Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

Comment: Presumably `PATH` is not set correctly on your system. Usually, MacTeX should do this on installation, I thought. What does `echo $PATH` give you on the command line?

Comment: Within the preferences of  TeXstudio (advanced options) I set **Build->Commands ($PATH)** to /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/universal-darwin/

Comment: I don't think the additional compilations will pick that up. It needs to be set correctly for the system generally and not just the application environment. What does the `echo $PATH` on the command line give?