# how to show Mactex to the TeXwork

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I did instal MacTex on my computer, but Texworks and Texmaker do not see all latex commends. Only in terminal I can run latex, pdflatex and others. How to show those tools to TeXworks ???

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What versions of Mac OS X and MacTeX are you running?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [Texmaker: command not found on MacOS El Capitan](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/271221). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped, I just didn't know the name of directory /Library/tex/texbin.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Preferences for TeXworks and the Typesetting tab.

Adjust the top box to be like in the following picture:

[image]

You may have to remove the top entry if it is like `/usr/texbin`; use the - and + buttons, together with the arrows to place the `/Library/TeX/texbin` at the top.